# Remove display of location field in Current and Upcoming Events view - Joomla

Tags: civievent, joomla

We are using CiviCRM  4.6.28 on current Joomla version.
As we are using the training location in the title already we would like to remove the display of the location column as it is irritating if it shows (not available).

Is there any way of removing this without hindering further updates?
[image: Screenshot of frontende display upcoming events]

Comment: Suggest you add a screenshot to ensure your question makes sense to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said which page you are referring to but I'm guessing that this is the public HTML listing of events.  If so, the output is controlled by [this template](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/templates/CRM/Event/Page/ICalendar.tpl): `<civicrm root>/templates/CRM/Event/Page/ICalendar.tpl`

You can copy this to create a custom template and edit it to remove the location column.

Read more about customising templates here: [Page Templates](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Page+Templates)

Comment: Thanks so ver much. Just had to comment out two lines of code, take care that the page was not just called and then replace the ICalender.tpl file. Problem was : I had no idea where to look for the file in the first place. Tnx again

Comment: Glad that helped. You should see comments on the HTML code that show you which template is in use. Please mark this as the accepted answer by clicking on the tick by this answer if it helped you.